# Positioning Elements within a Max-Width Flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use css in order to position two images at opposite sides of a flexbox (column1), that's contained within a flexbox (header) itself. Both have max-widths of 1024px, and the layout of the page is such that the header and footer are fixed. I've searched for and applied the answers available on this site, but haven't found any solutions. This seems simple, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, please help.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 450px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#middleground {
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 450px;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
}

#footer {
  height: 80px;
  max-width: 1024px;
  min-width: 450px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.column1 {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {}

.nav {}

.column2 {
  max-width: 1024px;
}

.eightball {}

.column3 {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: auto;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="column1">
      <span class="logo"><a href="indx.html"><img src="Images/brand-logo-1.png" alt="logo" height="60" width="195"/></a></span>
      <span class="nav"><img src="Images/nav100.png" alt="logo" height="25" width="25"/></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middleground">
    <div class="column2">
      <span class="eightball"><a href="shop/8ball.html"><img src="Images/8ball.png" alt="logo" height="150" width="150"/></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="column3">
      <div class="copy">T I T L E &copy 2 0 1 7 </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML code? Where do you want to position them?

Comment: I'd like to position them at the opposite ends of column1, which is inside a flexbox header.

Comment: I use angular material as a helper library for flex, but the principle is the same I suppose, so: let parent layout flex row (as it seems you have), add the two images as direct children and have a third div between the two images that is set to `flex 1 1` i believe it is in css. Anyway, have a empty div take up as much space as possible between the images.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot. Now following the same logic, how can I center something within my footer, and position something else all the way to the right?

Comment: No problem. Assuming I understand you correctly, I suppose I would use flex for the centered content, and absolute positioning for the content to the right `position: absolute; right: 0`. Otherwise the centered content would be pushed slightly to the left to leave space for the right aligned content.

Comment: If it is OK for the centered content to be relative to the right content I would: `<div layout="row"><div layout layout-align="center center" flex>centered content</div><div>right content</div></div>` in angular material. Making the centered content take up as much space as possible by letting it flex.